# Mocking window.open results in error for render() jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, window

I am trying to mock `window.open` but adding a mock to "open" results in the strangest error:

```
 const mockedWindowOpen = jest.fn(),
        originalWindow: any = { ...window };
    const windowSpy = jest.spyOn(global, "window", "get");
    windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
      ...originalWindow,
      open: mockedWindowOpen
    }));
```

The error: `TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object` and it points to the render function. If I comment this block:

```
 windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
          ...originalWindow,
          open: mockedWindowOpen
        }));
```

Error doesn't show, but I can't check how many times the func was called. Any ideas?